# How to add a image into PyCharm on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter to make a GUI and everything works for me except getting an image to import. The error is this:

```
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "MainDisk/Users/Matt/PythonProjects/Car_image.jpg": no such file or directory
```

My line of code:

```py
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="MainDisk/Users/Matt/PythonProjects/Car_image.jpg")
```

Is this the way that you would import an image on Mac? Sorry I am very confused and just am not sure how to get this to work. The image is in the right place but I have to be doing something wrong clearly. Me and someone else had this working on a windows computer but can't get it to work on Mac.

Comment: Did you forget the leading `/` in the path? Without it, the path is a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(r"MainDisk/Users/Matt/PythonProjects/Car_image.jpg")
```